# How to solve "wget: unable to resolve host address"

Tags: dns, wget

I am running this as root:

```
# wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/nagios/nagios-4.0.1.tar.gz

--2015-11-17 20:31:46--  http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/nagios/nagios-4.0.1.tar.gz
Resolving prdownloads.sourceforge.net... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address “prdownloads.sourceforge.net”
```

Comment: Can you `ping` it? What does `dig prdownloads.sourceforge.net` yield?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following link instead :

```
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/nagios/nagios-4.x/nagios-4.0.1/nagios-4.0.1.tar.gz
```

---

Note : I don't know if you have a particular reason to want 4.0.1 but the latest version is 4.1.1 :

```
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/nagios/nagios-4.x/nagios-4.1.1/nagios-4.1.1.tar.gz
```

Comment: -bash: http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/nagios/nagios-4.x/nagios-4.1.1/nagios-4.1.1.tar.gz: No such file or directory

Comment: iam enter you sending link

Comment: With the wget ?